# Disable and empty an input field after an AJAX call using JSF and Richfaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jboss, richfaces

I am using **richfaces 4.2.0.Final** and have the following situation: within a `rich:dataTable`, in which each row describes an article in a shopping cart, I have an input field 
in which the user can input the quantity she wants to order. As soon as the user focuses on this input field, I have to perform some controls on the server (using Ajax) and if
the controls fail, I must empty the field and disable it.

My solution:

```
<rich:dataTable var="article" value="#{cart.articles} >
...
<rich:column>
<h:panelGroup id="orderQty">
<h:inputText id="qtyInput" value="#{article.qty}" disabled="#{article.controlsFailed}">
    <a4j:ajax event="focus" bypassUpdates="true"
        listener="#{requestBean.doAjaxControls(article)}"
        execute="@this" render="qtyInput " />
</h:inputText>
</h:panelGroup>

@RequestScoped
@Named
public class RequestBean{

    public void doAjaxControls(Article article){
        boolean everyThingOK = doControls();//....
        if (!everyThingOK){
            article.setControlsFailed(true);
            article.setQty(null);
        } else {
            article.setControlsFailed(false);
        }
    }

}
```

Before coming to this solution I tried several other combinations of execute/render, without succeeding in what I need (for example, I tried to use `execute="@none"` as I don't want
the value of qty to be updated on the server when I perform the ajax call, but this won't work). 
My problem is I know this solution is not perfect: when I focus on a position for which the control will fail, and I am faster to type in a quantity than the server performing the controls, the field will be disabled and the server value for article#qty still set to null, but I will see the value I typed in until the next rendering of qtyInput will happen. 
More strangely, if I execute this code on **JBoss EAP 6.0.0.GA** (AS 7.1.2.Final-redhat-1, which includes the module jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.2.Final-redhat-1),
every quantity typed in before doAjaxControls() is done will be cleared: this strange behaviour is fortunately not present with **JBoss EAP 6.0.1.GA** (AS 7.1.3.Final-redhat-4, jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.7.Final-redhat-1).

Do you know if/how could I improve my solution?

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: did you try it without bypassUpdates?

Comment: You can make the input readonly and set the readonly flag to false ajax oncomplete. So the user input will be blocked until the ajax finish.

Comment: Hi, yes I did: actually with or without bypassUpdates doesn't make any difference. Untfortunately I cannot do what you suggested with readonly as the customer doesn't want.. :(